# How would I host deb packages?

Tags: linux, github, hosting, travis-ci, deb

I'm currently working on a github project mainly focused on windows users, written in Java. Install4j allows for easy .deb/.rpm etc. package conversion...
We could just ditribute the .deb on the download side, but when looking at gitlab a while ago, I saw, that Gitlab is using packagecloud.io as a hosting service for their packages (usingtheir own [domain](https://packages.gitlab.com)), so they can be updated using apt-get.
My question is, if there is a free service working just like packagecloud.io (not launchpad or similar with baazar and that advanced stuff) which can either be hosted on our own server or a public server. Or if there even is a downloadable version of packagecloud.io which we could use on our own server.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Travis CI to run extra commands when the build succeeds. You can put in some conditions, so that the `deploy` stage will only be run if commit happens to have a tag name. See the [deployment documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/) to get going.

A number of providers are officially supported, [among which PackageCloud.io](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/packagecloud).

You might find the [`dpl` utility](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/packagecloud) useful, as it assists with writing and testing deployment settings.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I'm primarily searching for a package hosting software which I could use in order to make the packages available through Linux source lists

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenRepo: https://github.com/openkilt/openrepo

I think this is what you're asking for.  This is a package hosting server that can make packages available for both Debian (APT) and Red Hat (RPM) files.